Does anyone know how we can visualize the permissions in Azure DevOps?
It will be useful to see the overall permission if we have any script or automations to visualize the default permission used across the azure DevOps portal.
So we can understand and assign permissions to developers, testers, leads,managers and administrators.
I explored the Azure Documents for this, and it is kind of a theory and defined for each role and permission, but it will be quick and easy if we can see it in a visualization like a tree structure along with the inherited permission value.
So we can avoid unwanted permissions or inherited permissions being granted.

Try using the Azure DevOps CLI.
The az devops security commands can be used to manage security related operations, including (but not limited to):

az devops security group list: List all the groups in a project or organization.
az devops security group membership list: List memberships for a group or user.
az devops security permission list: List tokens for given user/group and namespace.
az devops security permission namespace list: List all available namespaces for an organization.


There is no any built-in feature or extension can provide visualization of overall permissions.
You can try to use the "az devops security" related Azure DevOps CLI to get the permission settings for a user, a group or a team.


Thank you @Bright Ran-MSFT, it helps me for my situation
